# Spring-проект успешно запускается, но результат не выводится на экран

Tags: java, spring, gradle, lombok

Только знакомлюсь со `Spring`. Необходимо сделать данный туториал - https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/rest/. Написал половину кода, что там дано. И в середине туториала нам предлагают запустить проект и посмотреть, что уже получилось! 
Получиться должно вот что:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вместо этого у меня по адресу `http://localhost:8080/` или `http://localhost:8080/employees` ничего не выводит(не получается получить доступ к сайту). Либо если через консольку, но итог тот же.
В `Idea` у меня проект успешно собирается и сам завершает свою работу без ошибок или предупреждений(`build succesfull`).

Все делал точно по туториалу, весь код изучал, а затем тупо `copy + past`(ошибок быть не может в коде).

`Java jdk v.12`; `Intelij Idea` последняя; `Gradle` свежий; ну и `Spring` соответственно актуальный.

Что выводит в `Idea`:

```java
17:11:47: Executing task 'bootRun'...

Starting Gradle Daemon...
Gradle Daemon started in 7 s 756 ms
> Task :compileJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :processResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :classes UP-TO-DATE

> Task :bootRun

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.5.RELEASE)

2020-03-05 17:13:30.295  INFO 8556 --- [           main] com.example.demo.PayrollApplication      : Starting PayrollApplication on LAPTOP-5TNNRU08 with PID 8556 (started by ����� in C:\Users\�����\Downloads\demo\demo)
2020-03-05 17:13:30.307  INFO 8556 --- [           main] com.example.demo.PayrollApplication      : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-03-05 17:13:33.892  INFO 8556 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2020-03-05 17:13:34.216  INFO 8556 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 258ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
2020-03-05 17:13:36.645  INFO 8556 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-03-05 17:13:38.084  INFO 8556 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2020-03-05 17:13:38.596  INFO 8556 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2020-03-05 17:13:39.158  INFO 8556 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.12.Final
2020-03-05 17:13:40.361  INFO 8556 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
2020-03-05 17:13:41.459  INFO 8556 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
2020-03-05 17:13:42.410  INFO 8556 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tuple.PojoInstantiator     : HHH000182: No default (no-argument) constructor for class: com.example.demo.Employee (class must be instantiated by Interceptor)
2020-03-05 17:13:43.758  INFO 8556 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2020-03-05 17:13:43.786  INFO 8556 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-03-05 17:13:46.342  INFO 8556 --- [           main] com.example.demo.PayrollApplication      : Started PayrollApplication in 18.615 seconds (JVM running for 22.629)
2020-03-05 17:13:46.629  INFO 8556 --- [           main] com.example.demo.LoadDatabase            : Preloading Employee(id=1, name=Bilbo Baggins, role=burglar)
2020-03-05 17:13:46.631  INFO 8556 --- [           main] com.example.demo.LoadDatabase            : Preloading Employee(id=2, name=Frodo Baggins, role=thief)
2020-03-05 17:13:46.641  INFO 8556 --- [extShutdownHook] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-03-05 17:13:46.642  INFO 8556 --- [extShutdownHook] .SchemaDropperImpl$DelayedDropActionImpl : HHH000477: Starting delayed evictData of schema as part of SessionFactory shut-down'
2020-03-05 17:13:46.673  INFO 8556 --- [extShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2020-03-05 17:13:46.678  INFO 8556 --- [extShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1m 17s
3 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 2 up-to-date
17:13:47: Task execution finished 'bootRun'.
```

КОД:

```java
package com.example.demo;

import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Data
@Entity
class Employee {

    private @Id @GeneratedValue Long id;
    private String name;
    private String role;

//    Employee() {}

    Employee(String name, String role) {
        this.name = name;
        this.role = role;
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example.demo;


import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
class EmployeeController {

    private final EmployeeRepository repository;

    EmployeeController(EmployeeRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    // Aggregate root

    @GetMapping("/employees")
    List<Employee> all() {
        return repository.findAll();
    }

    @PostMapping("/employees")
    Employee newEmployee(@RequestBody Employee newEmployee) {
        return repository.save(newEmployee);
    }

    // Single item

    @GetMapping("/employees/{id}")
    Employee one(@PathVariable Long id) {

        return repository.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new EmployeeNotFoundException(id));
    }

    @PutMapping("/employees/{id}")
    Employee replaceEmployee(@RequestBody Employee newEmployee, @PathVariable Long id) {

        return repository.findById(id)
                .map(employee -> {
                    employee.setName(newEmployee.getName());
                    employee.setRole(newEmployee.getRole());
                    return repository.save(employee);
                })
                .orElseGet(() -> {
                    newEmployee.setId(id);
                    return repository.save(newEmployee);
                });
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/employees/{id}")
    void deleteEmployee(@PathVariable Long id) {
        repository.deleteById(id);
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;

@ControllerAdvice
class EmployeeNotFoundAdvice {

    @ResponseBody
    @ExceptionHandler(EmployeeNotFoundException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    String employeeNotFoundHandler(EmployeeNotFoundException ex) {
        return ex.getMessage();
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example.demo;

public class EmployeeNotFoundException extends RuntimeException{

        EmployeeNotFoundException(Long id) {
            super("Could not find employee " + id);
        }
    }
```

```java
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long>{
}
```

```java
package com.example.demo;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@Slf4j
class LoadDatabase {

    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner initDatabase(EmployeeRepository repository) {
        return args -> {
            log.info("Preloading " + repository.save(new Employee("Bilbo Baggins", "burglar")));
            log.info("Preloading " + repository.save(new Employee("Frodo Baggins", "thief")));
        };
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example.demo;


import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class PayrollApplication {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PayrollApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

BULD.GRADLE:

```java
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.5.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    runtimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Comment: можно ссылку на весь проект на гитхабе?

Comment: https://github.com/Rogue06/demo.git - ссылка на проект

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оказывается все очень просто! 3 дня мучений и ошибка найдена!

В классе Employee временно закомментировал пустой конструктор, и забыл про него.

```java
package com.example.demo;

import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Data
@Entity
class Employee {

    private @Id @GeneratedValue Long id;
    private String name;
    private String role;

    Employee() {} // Закомментил его и забыл снять комменты

    Employee(String name, String role) {
        this.name = name;
        this.role = role;
    }
}
```